# email field is optional in passportjs facebook strategy

Tags: node.js, passport.js, facebook-login, facebook-oauth, passport-facebook

I wrote the code for login with facebook, everything works and I'm getting the user's email address. But there is another option on facebook which lets the user select the data my application is going to have access to.

[image]

If user clicks on that, he'll see the name and everything marked as required, but email is optional and the user can remove it from the data that is going to be provided to the app.

[image]

On the application, email is required. So how I can mark the email as required on facebook?

This is the snippet I'm using in the code.

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
        clientID: config.social.facebook.clientID,
        clientSecret: config.social.facebook.clientSecret,
        callbackURL: config.url+'auth/facebook/cb',
        enableProof: false,
        profileFields:['id', 'name', 'emails'],
        scope: "email"
    }, function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        // doing the rest of the thing
    }
));

// ...

app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', {scope: ['email']}));
app.get('/auth/facebook/cb', passport.authenticate('facebook'), function(req, res, next) {
    res.redirect("/");
});
```

Comment: I don't know if Passport gives a way to re-request permissions, but [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23799185/how-to-make-email-permission-required-when-logging-in-signing-up-a-user-using-th) seems to say you can manually redirect them to Facebook's authorization page, and add `auth_type=rerequest` to the URL.  [Facebook's API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#login) suggests that may be outdated, and you'll need to pass the `scope` parameter on the URL instead.  I'm not sure if that will work, but please let me know if it does.

Comment: Thanks @PawnStar, you pointed me to the right direction, I solved the issue and posted my answer.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out. It's definitely something useful to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem by re-requesting the permission.

Turns out I can add `authType: 'rerequest'` to `passport.authenticate('facebook', {scope: ['email'], authType: 'rerequest'})`.

What I did is to check if the `emails` field is present in the result, if not, I call `done` with an error.

```
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    if (profile.emails === undefined) {
        done('email-required')
        return;
    }
    // doing the rest of the thing
}
```

Then to catch the error, I had to write a custom callback for `passport.authenticate('facebook')`.

```
app.get('/auth/facebook/cb', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('facebook', function (err, user, info) {
        if (err) {
            if (err == 'email-required') res.redirect('/auth/facebook/rerequest');
            // check for other kinds of errors and show proper messages
            return;
        }
        req.user = user;
        // do the rest of the thing
    })(req, res, next)
});
```

As you see, I redirect the user to another route `/auth/facebook/rerequest` in case of error.

```
app.get('/auth/facebook/rerequest',
    passport.authenticate('facebook', {
        scope: ['email'],
        authType: 'rerequest' // this is important
    }
));
```

This will redirect the user to the same page on FB again and this time email field is required. I couldn't do this in the same route; apparently it was using the same generated code to communicate to fb which was not acceptable by fb.

And that's how I managed to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify email in Strategy in profileFields property

```
passport.use('facebook', new FacebookStrategy({
  clientID: config.facebook.appId,
  clientSecret: config.facebook.appSecret,
  callbackURL: config.facebook.callbackURL,
  profileFields: ['emails', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'locale', 'timezone']
}, function (token, refreshToken, profile, done) {
  // you will get emails in profile.emails
}));
```

Comment: It is already in the field and that is not what I was looking for. I already solved the problem if you look at my own answer. Thanks for your time :)