# Node JS passport.authenticate always return false

Tags: node.js, express

I am very new to node js and wanted to start a project on this. So I have been following this link -
 [email field is optional in passportjs facebook strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34164571/email-field-is-optional-in-passportjs-facebook-strategy) - in order to make sure that the email field is compulsory during the Facebook authentication. It worked well in such a way that when users uncheck the email field, it redirects the user to the same page until the user checks the field. However, when the user continues with the email field checked, the isAuthenticated() returns false all the time and thus redirects to '/login' instead of '/account'. How should i write in order to solve the problem? Attached is the snippets of my code. Thank you in advance.

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: config.facebook_api_key,
    clientSecret:config.facebook_api_secret ,
    callbackURL: config.facebook_callback_url,
    profileFields: ['id', 'emails', 'displayName']
    },function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {  
       if (profile.emails === undefined){
          done('email-required') 
          return;
       }
```

for the callback,

```
app.get('/auth/facebook/callback', function(req, res, next) {
passport.authenticate('facebook', function (err) {
    console.log('this is error '+ err);
    if (err) {
        if (err == 'email-required') res.redirect('/auth/facebook');
        // check for other kinds of errors and show proper messages
        return;
    }else{
        res.redirect('/account');
    }
})(req, res, next) });
```

at the '/account',

```
    app.get('/account', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
    res.render('account', { user: req.user });
    });
```

the ensureAuthenticated function:

```
    function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) { 
         return next();
        }
    res.redirect('/login')
    }
```